# Complex filtering on checkbox click in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I basically have two tables which I need to filter like this:

```
Table 1 : Users
Table 2 : BrandUsers
```

Now I've made the following HTML:

```
<div class="pop-us">
        <div class="pop-j">
            <div class="pop-journey">
                <?php  foreach($users as $user) {?>
                    <div class="pop-first-btn"><input class="check-user" type="checkbox" name="" value="<?=$user['id'] ?>"><?=$user['username'] ?></div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pop-city">
            <div class="pop-txt"><?=$this->translate('Please choose a user.')?></div>
            <!-- city -->

            <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($states); $i++) { ?>
                <div class="pop-city-co">
                    <?php for ($j = 0; $j < count($states[$i]['citys']); $j++) { ?>
                        <label><input class="check-city" type="checkbox" name="" value="<?=$states[$i]['citys'][$j]['cityId']?>" data-id="<?=$i ?>"><?=$states[$i]['citys'][$j]['cityName']?></label>
                    <?php  } ?>
                </div>
            <?php  } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer pop-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pop-close-us">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pop-save-us">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The left part of the modal popup lists all of the users... Now my wish is to when each some check-box is clicked in the left side, I'd like to pass the value of the UserId to the function and pass it to my query to search out the BrandUsers table... Now there are two types of things that I'd like to show on my modal popup..

When the user clicks on 1 user... All of the brands are listed out on the right side. The brands for which usedId exists in BrandUser table, I'd like to make them checked in the list, and the ones that are non-existent, I'd simply like to  leave them un checked...

How can I make an event when an check-box is checked on the left side so that I pass the parameter UserId to DB and then display something on the right side of the modal popup ??

Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

Make your checkboxes like this. Note that I have added a `data-id` attribute that has the user id.

```
<div class="pop-first-btn"><input class="check-user" type="checkbox" name="" data-id="<?=$user['id'] ?>" value="<?=$user['id'] ?>"><?=$user['username'] ?></div>
```

And then add this to attach click handlers to all checkboxes

```
$('.check-city').on('click',function() {
    var user_id = $(this).data('id);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://myserver.com/action' + 'user_id=' + user_id;
        success: function(data) {
           // Update modal popup with data
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.